# Transferring Image between applications over the internet - how to serialise your data?

Tags: c#, image, serialization

So I've been working on writing two C# applications using System.Net.Sockets;

The server/client connects.  I can serialise a captured image of the desktop using BinFormatter and I can send that data between applications and effectively 'share' the desktop that gets redrawn in the other app.

I want to move the server to ubuntu and have done some successful testing in relation to connecting between two machines windows/ubuntu across a network, similarly to the connectivity between two apps running on the one machine but across a network.

What I'm interested in, is if I want to have the server and client in two different locations, I need to understand the best way to serialise the data between the apps. It appears that it is frowned upon using the BinaryFormatter in this manner and wondering if someone could help provide some guidance on best practice here?

I've done some testing in relation to code where you can convert an Image to Base64String which no doubt has some merit... curious on your perspective.

Thanks!

Comment: Your image is binary, send it as such (as a png/jpeg for example).  Base64 is space inefficient and is only useful when your limited to sending textual data which is not the case with a socket and no defined protocol.

Comment: You should be able to save / persist / write (whatever the method is called) the image as the underlying image format (png, etc) - just send that. Write to a `MemoryStream`, access `GetBuffer()`, copy out `.Length` bytes (no more), then `SetLength(0)` so you can re-use it for the next image. Nothing more complicated needed here, surely?